# How to perform unsorted comparison of numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

In testing the output of line detection using `python-opencv`, I am having trouble performing an "unsorted" test against my expectations. From the beginning (to avoid an XY problem):

Given an array, `a`, that looks like:

```
import numpy as np                                                              

a = np.array([
    # x0, y0, x1, y1                                                           
    [[6, 263, 6, 84]],
    # x0, y0, x1, y1                                                        
    [[0, 92, 181, 4]]                                                           
])
```

I would like this to compare approximately equal to `target`:

```
target = np.array([                                                             
    [[7, 86, 5, 263]],                                                          
    [[1, 91, 182, 4]],                                                          
])
```

Note that each set of coordinates represent the start and end point of a line; the order of the two is unimportant and I would like the arrays to test "equal" regardless of this order.

My current approach to solving this involves:

1. Splitting the subarrays of 4 points into two of 2 points:

```
def reformat(arr):                                                     
    new_arr = []                                                                  
    for row in arr:                                                             
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = row[0]                                                 
        new_arr.append([[x0, y0], [x1, y1]])                                      
    return np.array(new_arr)                                                                                                                             

a = reformat(a)                                                                          
print(a)
```

This works as expected and outputs:

```
[[[  6 263]
  [  6  84]]

 [[  0  92]
  [181   4]]]
```

2. Sorting the reformatted array:

```
print(np.sort(a, axis=1))
```

This outputs:

```
[[[  6  84]
  [  6 263]]

 [[  0   4]
  [181  92]]]
```

whereas the desired output is:

```
[[[  6  84]
  [  6 263]]

 [[  0   92]
  [181  4]]]
```

i.e. the coordinate pairs are kept intact, but lexically sorted for each line.

Eventually, I would implement my test using:

```
np.testing.assert_allclose(                                                     
    reformat_and_sort(a),                                                       
    reformat_and_sort(target),                                                  
    atol=5                                                                      
)
```

How can I reformat and sort `a` and `target` such that `np.testing.assert_allclose` will not raise an `AssertionError`?

Answer (score 0):

This function should do it:

```
def sort_lines(arr):
    for k, line in enumerate(arr):
        arr[k] = line[np.argsort(line[1,:])[::-1]]
    return arr
```

So,

```
print(sort_lines(reformat(a)))
```

Outputs:

```
[[[  6  84]
  [  6 263]]

 [[  0  92]
  [181   4]]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned lexical sort in my question as I think the solution probably needs to go down that route; for example, if `a = [[[1, 9, 1, 20]]]`, then the current output of `sort_lines(reformat(a))` would be `[[[1, 20][1,  9]]]`.